# E-mails won't send Magento

Tags: email

I set up new email templates for everything that sends out an automated email eg. forgotten password, new order, invoice, shipment etc... and assigned them to their relevant places.

However, I've been testing them and none of them are coming through.

Anyone have any idea as to why?

Comment: Use SMTP Pro magento extension, may be solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up a cronjob?
Some emails are only being sent while cronjob is running.

Is your local mailserver configuration ok?

Answer (score 1):

As Reinsch stated, emails tend to be sent when cron.sh is run. More specifically, transactional emails are sent when the cron is run (invoices, forgotten password requests etc). If you are using linux, try going into your Magento install directory and manually running cron.sh. Once run, you should see your emails start coming through. If that works then you need to add an entry to the crontab by doing the following;

1. type `crontab -e`
2. create a new line and add `*/1 * * * * sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh`